# Using Roslyn to compile a solution with an empty project gives an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

I am trying to use Roslyn to compile a VS2013 solution. The solution has many projects, one of which has no .CS files (we just use it to store JS and CSS files. It has a bunch of MSBuild steps to minify, lint, etc. these files).

When I run the solution through Roslyn, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException : The target
>   "Compile" does not exist in the project.

Here's the code I'm using to compile:

```
await MSBuildWorkspace.Create().OpenSolutionAsync(solutionFilePath);
```

How can I prevent this? The solution builds just fine in VS2013.

EDIT: as requested, here's the stack trace

```
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at [My Code]
--InvalidProjectFileException
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.ProjectFile.<BuildAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpProjectFileLoader.CSharpProjectFile.<GetProjectFileInfoAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.<LoadProjectAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.<GetOrLoadProjectAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.<OpenSolutionAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at [My Code]
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: If you don't have a C# compilation target, Roslyn won't be able to do anything with your solution.

Comment: It sounds like you should actually be running MSBuild directly, not Roslyn.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SLaks: the solution has a large number of C# projects and just one project without a C# compilation target. I'm using Roslyn since I'm performing my own analysis of the source code, not simply trying to compile to IL. Roslyn works fine for another solution that's a mix of F# and C# (it compiles the C#, that is). Is there a way to make it ignore the one project when loading the workspace?

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks: I've added the stack trace to the post

Comment: Downvoter: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Roslyn assumes that all `.csproj` projects are actual C# projects with a C# compilation task.

For non-C# projects, you should use a different extension, such as `.proj`.

You could also file a bug against Roslyn asking them to skip projects with no compilation task.